# When do onRestart method get called in Android?

Tags: android

While we are having onStart method, what is the purpose of onRestart method?

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }



 @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }
```

Comment: Check this out - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html#Start

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the activity lifecycle there is your `onStart()` and `onRestart()` methods with explanations

[image]

more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 11):

One case of `onRestart()` being called is when user presses home button and comes to launcher screen. In this case, activity is not destroyed and pause/stop events are fired. When user opens your app again, `onRestart()` for that activity is called before `onStart()`. You can find example [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity).

Comment: Isn't onCreate never called in this instance? according to the diagram on their documentation, it is called before onStart, but doesn't specify that onCreate is called.

Answer (score 9):

The `onRestart()` method will be called whenever the `Activity` comes back from the invisible state. Suppose, we pressed the home button of the device and coming back, this `onRestart()` will be invoked. For more info about this, please go through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Answer (score 3):

You can read all about the Activity's lifecycle on Android developers: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart()

Taken directly from there:

> Called after onStop() when the current activity is being re-displayed
>   to the user (the user has navigated back to it). It will be followed
>   by onStart() and then onResume().
>
> For activities that are using raw Cursor objects (instead of creating
>   them through managedQuery(android.net.Uri, String[], String, String[],
>   String), this is usually the place where the cursor should be
>   requeried (because you had deactivated it in onStop().
>
> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Only 100% sure that `onRestart` is called is when you **navigate away** and then **navigate back** to the activity.

On the other hand, when you press home button and the app moved to background, there is no way we can know whether the app is destroyed by OS to claim back resources or it is still reside on memory. If the app is destroyed then `onCreate` will be called. Otherwise if the app is still available in memory then `onRestart` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

> Note: Because the system retains your Activity instance in system memory when it is stopped, it's possible that you don't need to implement the onStop() and onRestart() (or even onStart() methods at all. For most activities that are relatively simple, the activity will stop and restart just fine and you might only need to use onPause() to pause ongoing actions and disconnect from system resources.
>
> Called after onStop() when the current activity is being re-displayed to the user (the user has navigated back to it). It will be followed by onStart() and then onResume().

For activities that are using raw Cursor objects (instead of creating them through managedQuery(android.net.Uri, String[], String, String[], String), this is usually the place where the cursor should be requeried (because you had deactivated it in onStop().

Answer (score 0):

`onRestart()` is called after `onStop()` when the current activity is being re-displayed to the user.

e.g. The user has navigated back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [NightFury's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437146/nightfury) answer. The onRestart() method is a callback method in the Android Activity lifecycle that is called when the activity is restarting after having been stopped.

**Some use cases:**

1. If an activity is paused or stopped and the user returns to it, the onRestart() method can be used to resume the activity from its paused or stopped state.
2. In some cases, the onRestart() method can be used to refresh the data displayed in the activity. For example, if the activity displays a list of items that are fetched from a server, the onRestart() method can be used to refresh the list after the user returns to the activity.
3. When the configuration of the device changes (such as screen rotation), the onRestart() method is called. This can be used to update the activity's layout or other resources to accommodate the new configuration.
4. Error handling: If an activity has encountered an error and was stopped, the onRestart() method can be used to reset the activity and handle the error.