# How to run code when app is re-entered after going to home (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, overriding

I want to run some code after I hit my home button and the re-open the app. How do I run code when the app is re-opened (Not After Being Killed) in android-studio?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `onStop()` method or `onDestroy()` , if you will close totally that Activity use `onDestroy()` and if you just will put it in background you can use `onStop()`

Doc for [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy())

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can
>   happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called
>   finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this
>   instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between
>   these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Doc for [onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onStop())

> Called when you are no longer visible to the user. You will next
>   receive either onRestart(), onDestroy(), or nothing, depending on
>   later user activity.

i saw you edited your question, look at the lifecycle

[image]

Like sagar says, you can use `onResume()` in order to recover your current Activity

Comment: But I want it to run on reopen.

Comment: you can use onCreate() method when it reopens, it will relaunch your activity, and then run onStart()

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the action in `onResume()` method. This is the state in which the app interacts with the user. The app stays in this state until something happens to take focus away from the app. Do note that there is no differentiation between Activity coming from background to foreground or Activity created from scratch. `onResume()` will be called whenever app enters foreground state.

In order to differentiate it in `onResume()` you need to maintain a `boolean` flag. You can set the flag in `onStop()` and check it in `onResume()`.

This approach will only work, if the OS hasn't killed the process, hosting your Activity, due to memory constraints. In this case your Activity will be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onRestart() since when you left your activity to go home it goes into onStop() and after that when you launch it system will call onRestart() the onStart().
for more info refer following  ans:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35476531/7271231