# what is the purpose of onRestart state?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm learning android recently, I am confused about the use of onRestart state. What is the purpose of onRestart state when we can also put the code in onStart.

I've tried to put some code in onStart and onRestart separately. However, no difference is spotted.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("state","create");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i("state","restart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("state","start");
    }
}
```

I understand how the android lifecycle works and when is each state starts.

**My question is when do I need to use onRestart if we can put all the code in onStart as well?**

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476452/when-do-onrestart-method-get-called-in-android

Comment: @NileshRathod I've read that question, when activity is returned, the state will be onRestart() --> onStart() --> onResume() etc.. However what i want to know is, the code i put into onRestart() is possibly work if i put them into onStart() as well. So in what situation i should put my code in onRestart() not onStart().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913845/7666442